# In Python turtle how can I write a timedelay

Tags: python, timedelay

I am wondering how to create a time delay with the turtle function. Would it be part of a function that loops to create one when needed?

Comment: Which version of python turtle are you referring to? Did you consider `turtle.screendelay(x), where x is time in milliseconds between screen updates?

Comment: @ZF007, neither the current Python 2 turtle library, nor the current Python 3 turtle library, include a function named `screendelay()`.  Which version of Python turtle are you referring to?

Comment: minor type. It should be `screen.delay(x)` or `turtle.delay(x)`. Py2.7. Dallonsi posted code after my remark so I didn't poste an answer as it would be just duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
import turtle

t = turtle

t.forward(100)
t.delay(1500)
t.forward(100)
```

Don't hesitate to read the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.delay)

Answer (score 3):

As @dallonsi said, delay() is the function for slowing down the turtle, and if you want to specify a delay time, the number inside the () are milliseconds, so 1000 is one second. In @dallonsi's example, 1500 is 1.5 seconds. Hope this helps.